# How to allow an app to auto-update on Citrix and Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2019, citrix

First, I'm not an IT guy. I'm a software developer. A lot of customers ask how to install my company's program on Citrix and Windows Server. My understanding is limited, but I believe they often have a template of install products. When a user logs on, that template of the OS and apps is given to them with a copy of user files that roam with them.

Our application needs to auto-update to keep up with changes in our API and get bug fixes. Currently the application installs into the user's LocalAppData folder. It seems like Citrix often treats these as temp files and aren't part of the template. This means the app is wiped after every user session. Our workaround is to add a logon script that install the program. It means that app takes 10-20 seconds to show up on their desktop. It also means updates must be downloaded every session.

So my question is -- is there a way to install the program into Program Files that allows us to Auto-Update within a Citrix environment? It seems like big apps install some kind of service under a special user that has permissions to auto-update. But it would still need to update every time because the template would revert it to it's initial state when on the next session.

Does Citrix have some method for persisting updated apps across sessions? Or is this a pipe dream and it must be redownloaded at the start of each session?

There is very little guidance for developers on these topics and I really need some information and thoughts from the IT side of things to understand the best approach.

Comment: Whatever solution you decide, you will need to test it on a similar deployment endowment, there is no magic solution to problem you describe.  Chrome for the longest time was installed in %AppData% instead of Program Files so a normal unelevated user could update it.  It's current (default) directory appears to be %ProgramData% for similar reasons. You don't want to hear my actual suggestion to an application that changes as often as you suggest it changes.

Comment: You need to look at your app's installation methods and options, and the app support capabilities of Citrix or any other platforms your app may need to run on, and you need to match one to the other. If you want Citrix, you can't use AppData.

Answer (score 1):

Programs like Microsoft Teams install one copy on a server in the program files, as server-wide installer, and each user has a launcher that performs a quick install from that installed copy into their local userprofile.

This approach is necessary to allow to update the main install without it being in use by users. Any subsequent login by a user will then get their local install updated.

I have no experience with citrix so I can't tell you how to keep the app in a local profile, but this may not even be necessary. As there is a local install in the program files, the update from local should be so quick that it is not a bad way to do this.

Comment: The Citrix product the author is referring to is a similar program to VMware Horizon, where you have a thin client, and every time the user logs into the network a VM is displayed.  There are some differences but the product is indeed a hypervisor.

Comment: Yes, I know what Citrix is. I just never managed one from the backend, only has been on the client side.